# Combo box css in Qt

Tags: css, qt, qtstylesheets

I want to make this combo box in Qt look like this designed combo box in Figma. I'm not that good with CSS.
This is the original combo box in Qt :
[image]

This is the design I want to make:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

this one i make the original appearance none then i make custom button for it this the code

css:

```
   .select-menu{
    appearance: none;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    background-image: url(arrow.svg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right 25%; 
    background-size: 20px; 
    color: #333;
    width: 130px;
    }

.select-menu::-ms-expand{
display: none;
}
```

[image]